# Why is my PS4 controller blinking twice and then just turning off?

Tags: ps4, controllers

I’ve tried pressing the button in the back of the controller, and when I charge it, it only shows orange but doesn’t flash/pulse so it also won’t charge. I don’t know what to do because I tried both my controllers and had the same issue.

Comment: Is it an original PS4 controller?